# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'get_default_graph' python3

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I tried to get following program to work:
https://github.com/mattdangerw/keras-text-generation

In my CMD (Windows 10) I entered:

```
python train.py
```

I got following error:

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
Loading data...
corpus length: 1223047
vocab size: 41
x.shape: (44608, 50)
y.shape: (44608, 50, 1)
x_val.shape: (4288, 50)
y_val.shape: (4288, 50, 1)
Data load time 0.958162784576416
Building model...
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "train.py", line 42, in <module>
    main()
File "train.py", line 37, in main
    model.train(**vars(args))
File "D:\IoT\Aufgabe4\task3\keras-text-generation\model.py", line 135, in train
    self._build_models(batch_size, embedding_size, rnn_size, num_layers)
File "D:\IoT\Aufgabe4\task3\keras-text-generation\model.py", line 92, in _build_models
    model = Sequential()
File "C:\Users\Michael\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\sequential.py", line 87, in __init__
    super(Sequential, self).__init__(name=name)
File "C:\Users\Michael\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\legacy\interfaces.py", line 91, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Michael\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\network.py", line 96, in __init__
    self._init_subclassed_network(**kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Michael\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\network.py", line 294, in _init_subclassed_network
    self._base_init(name=name)
File "C:\Users\Michael\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\network.py", line 109, in _base_init
    name = prefix + '_' + str(K.get_uid(prefix))
File "C:\Users\Michael\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py", line 74, in get_uid
    graph = tf.get_default_graph()
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'get_default_graph'
```

Python Version:

```
python --version
    Python 3.7.3
```

Keras Version:

```
python -c "import keras; print(keras.__version__)"
    Using TensorFlow backend.
    2.2.4
```

Tensorflow Version:

```
python -c "import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.__version__)"
    2.0.0-alpha0
```

I also installed pip and with pip I have also installed colorama, which is needed.

How to fix it? A friend tested the same program and performed the same installation and configuration, but without any error messages. I think it`s a problem with tensorflow. Am I right?

Comment: try this `from tensorflow.python.keras import backend as k`

Answer (score 1):

Keras does not currently support TensorFlow 2.0, since it is still an alpha version. You either need to use `tf.keras`, or downgrade TensorFlow to 1.13 in order to use the official `keras` package.

Comment: The solution was to uninstall with pip uninstall keras and pip uninstall tensorflow. After that I installed with pip install tensorflow==1.130rc1 and pip install keras==2.0.0 the "right working" versions

Answer (score 0):

This is a known Tensorflow/Keras bug, read more here:

https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/12379

Solution as per link (same as in comment by @Vishal):

I changed the imports from `keras.something.something` to `tensorflow.keras.something` and the issue seemed to have gone away. Putting it here for others to benefit.